# Echo writes trailing space in batch file

Tags: batch-file

With this batch file, I get a trailing space on every line in the output txt file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims==" %%A in (trimlist.txt) do set string=%%A & echo !string:,=.!>>trimlist-new.txt
```

How do I go about removing the trailing spaces? I want to avoid creating a new batch file to do so if possible.

Comment: @Dodekeract batch files have been [legacy technology on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) since 2006 - *ten years and four or five major Windows versions ago*. Not too surprisingly, PowerShell has more string handling options, e.g. `gc trimlist.txt |% { ($_ -split '=')[0] -replace '3', '.' } >> trimlist-new.txt` - or various other ways of writing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space between `%%A` and `=` is being included in your string. To avoid it, you can either have a multi-line `for` loop, or simply put quotes around your `set` statement.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims==" %%A in (trimlist.txt) do set "string=%%A" & echo !string:,=.!>>trimlist-new.txt
```